# How to rename JSON properties on child class

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, fasterxml

Here an easy example:
Suppose I have two classes, MyEntity and Person:

```
public class MyEntity {
  long id;
  String name;
}

public class Person extends MyEntity {
  String lastName;
  int age;
  // other fields
}
```

So far no problem. Now I want them to be parsed to JSON using Jackson annotations. Supposing I have many other entities that extend MyEntity and all of them have the JSON field `name` but particularly `name` must be parsed to `lastName` in `Person` class. Is there any way to do that? What would be logical for me would be an annotation like (**I made up this code!! just to get the idea**):

```
@JSONFieldValue(subClass = Person.class, field = "name", JSONName = "lastName")
public class MyEntity{}
```

Do you guys know of any way to achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson by default uses setter methods for deserializing and infers the JSON field name by the setter method name according to Java beans conventions.

To parse a JSON field named `name` into a Java class field named `lastName` just add this setter at `Person`:

```
void setName(String name) {
    lastName = name;
}
```

or annotate the normal setter in `Person`:

```
@JsonProperty( "name" )
void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```